# Is there a way to shorten the code of getting one user from postgres DB in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I use node.js and pg library (node-postgres) to interact with database.

This is the code I use to retrieve one user of specific ID:

```
const { rows: users } = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1", [id]);
const user = users[0];
```

Even if there is only one record postgres always returns an array, so I retrieve this first item in the second line.

Is there a way to shorten this code if there is only one user? Like make it one line instead of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly get the first `user` object by destructuring the `rows` array

```
const { rows: [user] } = await db.query(...)
```